# view a meteor cursor as json in shell

Tags: meteor

I am trying to view my data through the meteor shell, but the commands return a cursor, which is not very readable. For example:

```
$ meteor shell
> Posts.find({})
{ _mongo: 
   { _observeMultiplexers: 
      { '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"53WCn8zc43D8zM9C4","services.resume.loginTokens.hashedToken":"OqNw4yvgPHQKKJO8/QKjFbrt5doAAxIKwMuemQ/Cd+o="},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"_id":1}}}': [Object],
        '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration","selector":{},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"secret":0}}}': [Object],
        '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"53WCn8zc43D8zM9C4"},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"profile":1,"username":1,"emails":1}}}': [Object],
        '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"notifications","selector":{"userId":"53WCn8zc43D8zM9C4","read":false},"options":{"transform":null}}': [Object],
        '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"comments","selector":{"postId":"RNpbfHxXkoMWPPGQQ"},"options":{"transform":null}}': [Object] },
     _onFailoverHook: { nextCallbackId: 6, callbacks: [Object] },
     db: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        databaseName: 'meteor',
        serverConfig: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _applicationClosed: false,
        slaveOk: false,
        bufferMaxEntries: -1,
        native_parser: false,
        bsonLib: [Object],
        bson: [Object],
        bson_deserializer: [Object],
        bson_serializer: [Object],
        _state: 'connected',
        pkFactory: [Object],
        forceServerObjectId: false,
        safe: false,
        notReplied: {},
        isInitializing: true,
        openCalled: true,
        commands: [],
        logger: [Object],
        tag: 1432228545603,
        eventHandlers: [Object],
        serializeFunctions: false,
        raw: false,
        recordQueryStats: false,
        retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
        numberOfRetries: 60,
        readPreference: [Object] },
     _primary: '127.0.0.1:3001',
     _oplogHandle: 
      { _oplogUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/local',
        _dbName: 'meteor',
        _oplogLastEntryConnection: [Object],
        _oplogTailConnection: [Object],
        _stopped: false,
        _tailHandle: [Object],
        _readyFuture: [Object],
        _crossbar: [Object],
        _baseOplogSelector: [Object],
        _catchingUpFutures: [],
        _lastProcessedTS: [Object],
        _onSkippedEntriesHook: [Object],
        _entryQueue: [Object],
        _workerActive: false },
     _docFetcher: 
      { _mongoConnection: [Circular],
        _callbacksForCacheKey: {} } },
  _cursorDescription: 
   { collectionName: 'posts',
     selector: {},
     options: { transform: null } },
  _synchronousCursor: null }
```

How do I display this result as an array of js objects? I want my query results to be readable!

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for with `mongo shell` is `.fetch()`. So the answer to the question is in `meteor shell` run `Posts.find({}).fetch()`.

From [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find):

> When you want to retrieve the current list of documents from a cursor,
>   call the cursor's .fetch() method:

```
// get an array of posts
var postsArray = Posts.find().fetch();
```